# Consumption data of gasoline by month and city available?

Tags: data-request, city, energy

Any idea if there is a public source of gasoline consumption data for US cities?

I am looking at predicting changes in gasoline consumption as a function of recent technological innovations.

Comment: Welcome to Open Data SE! Could you please specify in which geographic region you're interested?

Answer (score 2):

a think tank in chicago has done some of this legwork for you, but the price is from 2007; pretty sure you can change it to reflect new prices. and while this is only going to give you a cost estimate, i imagine dividing the cost by price should give you the number of gallons. not sure if you can enter a city, but you can search by zip/address so you could also compile them into cities/localities:
http://abogo.cnt.org/

there's also the urban mobility report, which should give you exactly what you want:
http://mobility.tamu.edu/ums/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if EIA data will be granular enough for what you're looking for:
http://www.eia.gov/petroleum/data.cfm#consumption

Looks like they define their regions:
http://www.eia.gov/petroleum/gasdiesel/gas_geographies.cfm#city-county

Comment: The EIA has limited data on this subject. I don't believe they have consumption data. This is from their FAQ: Does EIA have energy consumption and price data for cities, counties, or by zip code?

the U.S. Energy Information Administration (EIA) does not have data by zip code. EIA has gasoline price data for some cities, and it has data for electric and natural gas distribution utilities: